# Abelian covering of link complement

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, knot-theory

I'm considering finite index abelian (regular) covering of link  complement:

$$ X \rightarrow S^3\setminus L$$

where $L$ is a minimally twisted chain link.

I'm interested in covering space. Can we compute its cohomology (or maybe fundamental group) in terms of  $S^3\setminus L$? Is it true that $X$ is  link complement? I would appreciate any helpful tip on this.

Comment: What is a (the?) "finite index universal abelian cover" of a manifold?

Comment: For the fundamental group of a link complement, the relevant Google search terms are "Wirtinger's algorithm" and "Wirtinger presentation."

There's a really nice chapter of Rolfsen's "Knots and Links" that talks about coverings of $S^3 \setminus L$ using the fact that every oriented link in $S^3$ bounds a Seifert surface.

Comment: The homology of abelian covers of link exteriors, and of branched covers of links in spheres were two of the first invariants ever considered, in the beginning of knot theory.  So yes we can compute these things.  Some have taught computers to do it for us.

Comment: To expand on Sam Nead's question: the "universal abelian cover" of a manifold $M$ usually means the covering space corresponding to the kernel of the Hurewicz map $\pi_1(M)\to H_1(M,\mathbb{Z})$. In the case of a link complement, this covering spaces *never* has finite index (because $H_1(M,\mathbb{Z})$ is infinite). So the words "finite index" make the question unclear. Assuming you just want to delete the words "finite index", many tools are available, as the other comments have indicated. But please edit to clarify!

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow! Please use the [Contact Us](/contact) form to have your accounts merged, to regain full control over your posts.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes there are (implemented!) algorithms to compute the (co)homology of manifolds and their covers.
2. In general finite covers of link complements, even abelian ones, need not be link complements themselves.  As an example, consider the snappy manifold s776.  I believe that this is the minimally twisted three component chain link.  The manifold s776 has as a double cover the manifold with triangulation isosig “mLvMALPAQbeffeijjikllldadedadedaaed”. This cover has torsion in its first homology, so it is not a link complement in the three-sphere.

Answer (score 0):

A nice hands-on method for computation could be using C-complexes. To get started, there is a fantastic paper on them by Cimasoni-Florens.